# playframework running task everyday with Akka

Tags: java, akka, actor, playframework-2.2

I am looking for simple example/manual/tutoral of usage Akka Aktor in PlayFramework with Java.
I've tried already this tutorial:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaAkka
but I cant make it compile.

I would like to count in every 24 houres some data and send an email from system. I would like to use for it Aktor.

I use playFramework 2.2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My working solution (for playFramework 2.2.4) based on post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706767/1066240

My Global.java class in /app/Global.java

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Seconds;

import actions.ValidateApplicationLicence;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.Props;
import play.Application;
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.Logger;
import play.libs.Akka;
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    //ActorRef myActor = Akka.system().actorOf(new Props(ValidateApplicationLicence.class));

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application application) {

        Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
                Duration.create(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Logger.info("After 10 sec and after EVERY 5 sec  ---    " + controllers.common.Index.getDate(null));
                    }
                },
                Akka.system().dispatcher()
        );

        Akka.system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(
                Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Logger.info("ON START ---    " + controllers.common.Index.getDate(null));
                    }
                },
                Akka.system().dispatcher()
        );
//      Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
//                Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), //Initial delay 0 milliseconds
//                Duration.create(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES),     //Frequency 30 minutes
//                myActor,
//                "tick",
//                Akka.system().dispatcher(),
//                null
//        );
    }
    public static int nextExecutionInSeconds(int hour, int minute){
        return Seconds.secondsBetween(
                new DateTime(),
                nextExecution(hour, minute)
        ).getSeconds();
    }

    public static DateTime nextExecution(int hour, int minute){
        DateTime next = new DateTime()
                .withHourOfDay(hour)
                .withMinuteOfHour(minute)
                .withSecondOfMinute(0)
                .withMillisOfSecond(0);

        return (next.isBeforeNow())
                ? next.plusHours(24)
                : next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample for [Play 2.0.4 in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14706767/1066240), anyway in 2.1 several things changed (mainly imports)