# How to schedule complex tasks using Scala/Play 2.3?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

I'm looking to schedule something to run once per day, and the code I want to run involves making updates to entries in the database. I have managed to schedule the running of some simple code by overriding the onStart method in Global.scala using Akka, as follows

```
override def onStart(app: Application) = {
    Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0.second, 1.second) {
        println("hello!")
    }
}
```

The issue is that I want to do something more complicated than logging here, I want to make updates to the database, so I would want to call some function in a models file (models/SomeTable.scala), but I can't import that code in Global.scala.

It sounds like if I want to do something more complicated like that, I should be using Akka's actor system, but I am far from understanding how that works. I've found documentation for how to create Actors through [Akka's documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/index-actors.html?language=scala), though how to incorporate that into my Play project is unclear. Where do I write this Actor class, and how is that imported (what is Global.scala allowed to have access to..?)? And if I don't need to use actors for this, does anyone have some insight into how imports and such work in this part of a Play project?

*Note that this part of the Play framework underwent large changes going from Play version 2.3.* to 2.4.*, so it definitely should not be expected that solutions in 2.4.* would likely work here*

The information I've gotten above has come mostly from [Play's documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAkka#Scheduling-asynchronous-tasks), along with a bunch of related SO questions:

[How to schedule task daily + onStart in Play 2.0.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706300/how-to-schedule-task-daily-onstart-in-play-2-0-4)

[how to write cron job in play framework 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178713/how-to-write-cron-job-in-play-framework-2-3)

[Scheduling delaying of jobs tasks in Play framework 2.x app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361437/scheduling-delaying-of-jobs-tasks-in-play-framework-2-x-app)

[Where is the job support in Play 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339714/where-is-the-job-support-in-play-2-0)

[Was asynchronous jobs removed from the Play framework? What is a better alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007478/was-asynchronous-jobs-removed-from-the-play-framework-what-is-a-better-alternat/31019858#31019858)

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you definitely need to read about akka.

But for your specific task you do not need to import anything into `Global`. You just need to start your worker actor. And this actor can schedule regular action itself. As Template

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, Cancellable, Props}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class MyActor extends Actor {
  private var cancellable: Option[Cancellable] = None


  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    super.preStart()
    cancellable = Some(
      context.system.scheduler.schedule(
        1.second,
        24.hours,
        self,
        MyActor.Tick
      )(context.dispatcher)
    )
  }

  override def postStop(): Unit = {
    cancellable.foreach(_.cancel())
    cancellable = None
    super.postStop()
  }

  def receive: Receive = {
    case MyActor.Tick =>
        // here is the start point for your execution
        // NEW CODE WILL BE HERE
  }
}

object MyActor {
  val Name = "my-actor"
  def props = Props(new MyActor)
  case object Tick
}
```

Here you have an actor class. With preStart and postStop (read more about [actors lifecycle](https://medium.com/akka-for-newbies/actor-lifecycle-94b05bd2f600)) where defined and cancelled schedule. Scheduled action is sending `Tick` message to `self` (in other words actor will receive each 24 hours `Tick` message and if `receive` is defined for `Tick`, this message will be processed).
So you just need to start you implementation where I placed comment.

From Global you just need to start this action in `onStart`:

```
Akka.system.actorOf(MyActor.props, MyActor.Name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Where should this Actor code be written though?

Comment: Anywhere. It is just a usual class. I would place it in some usual package outside of play structure (not in `controllers`, `views` or other standard play-related package), e.g. com.example.myapp.actors, but you are free to choose any other place