# Is there a scala version of play.libs.Time.CronExpression in Play 2.3.9?

Tags: scala, playframework, cron, akka

I'm trying to implement a cron style scheduled task in my Scala Play server.  I liked the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17172580/1334662). However, my scala application does not recognize [play.libs.Time.CronExpression](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.9/api/java/index.html?play/libs/Time.CronExpression.html) as a valid object.  Is there a more idiomatic way to do Cron Expression Akka job scheduling in Scala Play?

Comment: You could try https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: You can pull it in, it's just included by default in play-scala